# LibraryNotFoundException while running java code that invokes dlls

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have written a code that requires 2 dll's at runtime.I have those dll files in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin`. 
I have set the environment variable PATH accordingly.
It compiled successfully and then while running it gives the following  error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at teamdev.jxcapture.Capture.captureActiveWindow(Unknown Source)
        at ppb.activewindow.execute(activewindow.java:24)
        at ppb.activewindow.main(activewindow.java:68)
Caused by: com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: Cannot find JNIWrapper nativ
e library (jniwrap.dll) in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\
jre\bin\jniwrap.dll
```

Could anybody please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\java\Jdk 1.6\jre\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin` are not the same thing. Is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry my typing mistake .... I am using the same JRE as the JDK

Comment: Can you share the code where the dll's are being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `java.library.path` should be the *directory* containing the DLLs, not the filename of the DLLs themselves. It looks like your `java.library.path` is set to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin\jniwrap.dll
```

instead of

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DLL is not being found on the Java Library Path. See this - http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/load.html

Try moving JDK to a path without spaces.